# List page for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I have created a custom post type in wordpress and have 90% of the functionality working correctly, but I am having a bit of trouble trying to create a custom listing page template.

Currently it is using the default index.php page to bring out all the posts and I have tried to override this by creating a page-post-type.php page but didn't seem to work.

What would be the best method for creating a custom post type listing page?

Cheers,
Jamie.

Comment: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-display-post-based-on-custom-fields-with-a-custom-query

Comment: you can refer my answer on same question on this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175120/custom-posts-on-different-pages/270656#270656
hope it helps you.

Comment: Note: The wprecipes.com link is dead, and the resulting page on wphacks cannot be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to create archive page for custom post type, create `archive-{post_type}.php` and it'll display you custom post type content.

Also see codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display

Comment: Note that if you've named your custom post type post-typename instead of post_typename, it won't work.  The hyphen (-) in template names separates the properties that map to the template file, and custom type names that include a hyphen break the mapping.

Comment: Why should want to create a `archive-{post_type}.php` page. When we make ` 'has_archive' => true,` when registrring custom post type you can access it like `domain.com/custom_post_type` (depend on the permalink structure). Am I wrong?